# C++: How to pass results from one class to another class?

Tags: c++, class

I have one class to read data (data.h & data.cpp), one class to analysis data (analysis.h & analysis.cpp) and another one to do calculation based on two previous classes (calculation.h & calculation.cpp).
I wonder how can I pass the results from data class to analysis class and later on from both of them to calculation class. I tried to put the data.h into analysis.cpp but it didn't work out
Thank you for your time

Comment: This sounds like a dubious design from the very first sentence. Reading data is an _algorithm_. Algorithms are best implemented as _functions_. Objects are to combine state (data) with behavior (member functions). Algorithms have no state, but side effect and/or a result. Also, _files_ are something different than _classes_. Source code is stored in files, but how many classes are there per file (or none, you can write perfectly legal C++ programs without any classes) you are free to decide. This is the 3rd or 4th time I write this in less than a week. _Java really poisons programmers' minds._

Comment: Many patterns, e.g. Strategy pattern, utilise classes to implement algorithms

Comment: @sbi: David's got a good point.  Parsing data may be an algorithm, but often it's one with state, and that state exists between function calls.  Putting it into an object is a nice way to encapsulate that, and seen as a step from a beginning programmer's habit of using static-members/globals, an OO approach here is a good first step towards thread-safe functionality.  An overly file-per-class approach is something I also find extremely annoying... especially when they're including thousands of lines of headers and only a few dozen lines long... quite with you there.

Comment: @David: I would not have reacted so much to "I have one class to _parse_ data". @Tony: Yes, there are reasons to do otherwise. That's why I wrote "best". I could have substituted this for "usually", but now I can't edit it anymore. And, now that I read the question again, user479127 actually confuses classes and files. That "data.h" might not even contain a class (although my experience with C++ students coming from Java strongly suggests it does).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. @sbi: thx for making some concepts clear to me. @Tony: you got my supervisors point. They just wanted me to be familiar with OOP. Actually I'm learning C++ from scratch with just some prior programming knowledge from Fortran. Have a nice day every1

Answer (score 2):

In calculation.cpp, you'd #include data.h and analysis.h, then use data functions to retrieve the data, passing the result(s) to analysis, then those results to calculation.

This boils down to something roughly like...

```
#include "data.h"
#include "analysis.h"

Data data;
Analysis analysis;
while (data.get())
    analysis.process_more(data);
Calculation calculation(analysis);
calculation.report();
```

In other words, objects of the class types ARE the results.

Answer (score 0):

The definition for data goes in data.h

class Data { ... }

and include the file in analysis.cpp

#include "data.h"

and pass it as a reference

class Analysys
{
bool Analyse(Data &data);
}

Comment: Note that you need to declare the class in analysis.h, "class Data;", to be able to use it in signatures.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new structure in which you can store results from your class and use it to send your results over your classes.
For example:

```
Struct Result {
    bool dataResult;
    bool analisysResult;
};
```