# c++: how to pass a variable's value from one class to another?

Tags: c++

I have a class "A" that take its variables' values from the application's GUI. let us say one of these variables is "X". then, in another class "B", I would like to call this "X" and pass its value to another function.

what I did is that I created an object of class "A" called "objectA" in class "B", and then called the value of "X" as follow:

```
// class A:
void classA::function1(int gui_value){
    x= gui_value;
}
```

then in the another class:

```
//class B:
void classB::run(){
.
.
function2(/* I need to pass x here */); 
.
.
}
```

both functions and x are defined in the header file correctly.

what I did is that I created an object of classA (let us say: objectA) in the header file and call the value of "x" in "function2" in "classB" using "objectA" as follow:

```
//class B:
void classB::run(){
.
.
function2(objectA->x); 
.
.
}
```

Let us say "x" value equals "5", when I debug the value of "x" in function2, it gives me random number everytime i debug. So, I am just guessing that these random values are already exist in the memory, which means the value of "X" is not passed correctly.

I think, although the object is created, however it create a new instance of variable "x" everytime. i.e.: is not taking the value of "x" from classA, it is just create an object of classA with all its variables.

my problem is how to pass the vlaue of "x" that is obtained in classA directly to classB without creating a new instance of its variable ?

---

**Update:**

Thanks to ***doctorlove's*** answer, my code is now working fine. My problem was in initializing "objectA" after its creation and assigning a value to it. what I was doing is creating the object and passing it directly in "classB". That is why i was getting the random values as it was just a new object which have whatever value in the memory in the time of creation.

Comment: Possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957766/c-how-to-pass-results-from-one-class-to-another-class

Comment: @ClaireG: Thanks, I am checking it out ...

Comment: If I understand what you're saying correctly, I'm afraid you need to study the basics of C++ a bit more with books and tutorials. Unless X is  `static`, each instance of A has its own X and the code above doesn't do what you want at all.

Comment: provide minimal but complete example (please, no GUI code).

Comment: I'm not clear what's happening. objectA->X won't compile, but objectA.X might. Where do you create objectA? If it's just before you use it you haven't initialised it. Try to make it a member variable and initialise it in B's constructor

Comment: Post the code for class A and class B

Comment: @Mat: yes, exactly, you got my issue .. the problem is I am creating a new instance of X everytime I create the Object of class "A" .. my problem is I don't know how to pass the value of X as it is obtained by class A ..

Comment: How you do that depends on a lot of stuff. And there are huge amounts of examples of hundreds of different ways to do that all over the internet, in tutorials, examples and in books. If you're using Qt, study the tutorials and examples. They come with full source code and should help you understand the basic concepts of the usual ways of doing that in the context of Qt GUI programming.

Comment: @doctorlove: check my edited version please ..

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: check out the edit version of my question please ...

Comment: @Rania-Boy I still don't know where objectA is initialised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you are trying to do. If you have something like this...

```
class A
{
    private:
    int X;//ignoring any thing about encapsulation for now
};

class B
{
//...
    public:
    void DoSomething()
    {
        A objectA; 
        //makes objectA another A each time we get here, with X uninitialised
        //use objectA.X which has random numbers in
    }

};
```

this will behave similarly to the problem you describe. If you make `objectA` a member instead and initialise it properly it might do what you want. With `class A` as before,

```
class B
{
//...
    private:
    A objectA;
    public:
    B() 
    {
        objectA.X = 42;
    }
    void DoSomething()
    {
        //use member objectA.X 
    }

};
```

---

**EDIT**
Clearly in my example I have pulled 42 out of nowhere. If you have a sensible value from the gui, send it to the constructor of B. If it changes you'll need a reference to it instead.

```
explicit B(int gui_value)
{
    objectA.X = gui_value;
}
```

---

**EDIT2**
If you have an existing `objectA` someplace else, then pass *that* to the constructor

```
explicit B(const A & otherA)
    : objectA(otherA)
{
}
```

If that's not possible, your design needs improving. Without any code to look at I cannot help any more.

Comment: You got exactly my porblem is the first code, however, I don't want to hard-code the value of "x" in "classB" .. it should be obtained from the GUI that passes its values to "classA", one of these values is "x" value ...

Comment: @docorlove: no, not really .. the gui value is passed to classA from the mainwindow.cpp .. classB cann't get access the gui_value directly.

Comment: @Rania-Boy can class B see objectA at all? If not, you're doing it wrong

Comment: @Rania-Boy and there is only one objectA and it's initialised correctly? Then you can't be having the problem you described.

Comment: wait a minute .. I am just creating the object .. and passing it to the function that needs it .. what about this initialization ? do you think because it is not  initialized that is why I get the random values for "x" ? ..

Answer (score 1):

let's say you got a class  A with an private int variable i  , and  B with and private int variable X,

```
class A{
private:
int i;  
// if you want to use x within A you have to declare the  object here 
B  objectB;
.....
public :
int getI();
int setI();
};

// the second class  B 
class B(){
private :
int X;
......
public :
int getX();
void setX();
..

};
```

let'S say you have a  main() function

```
int main (){
  A objA;
  B objB;

  objB.setX(5);//X is now 5 
  objA.setI(objB.getx());  // i has the value of X which is 5 
...
}
```

Comment: I've tried the Setter and the Getter but the problem stayed still, i get random numbers for "x", and not the value that should be passed from the GUI ...

Comment: it depends on you GUI, what do you use to make it

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no compile time error on the creation of the `objectA`, the object is successfully been created.

To pass the variable, instead of using arrow operator use dot(.) operator 
`y = objectA.X`

Comment: Has it been created but X not initialised?

Comment: it doesn't work .. it gives me an error saying `no matching function to classB::classB()` !!!